# starts new thread inside Task.ContinueWith

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

i am building a WPF app where it needs job1 runs in the background; when job1 ends, it switches back to the UI thread using `Task.ContinueWith` and makes changes to the UI according to job1's result (in my case, starts another popup) and starts job2 in the background.

The problem is that, while job1 runs in a separate thread as it should, job2 runs in the UI thread (it blocks popup2). Maybe because job2 is started inside the `ContinueWith` block of task1? But why? It worked the first time, why not second time? How to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance!

```
enterPop(PopupTypes.popup1);
var task1 = new Task(() => job1()); //task runs in another thread
task1.ContinueWith(previousTask =>
    {   
    //**back in UI thread**
    //check result of job 1, start another popup in UI
    exitPopup();
    enterPop(PopupTypes.popup2);
    //**SUPPOSEDLY** starts another background thread for task 2
    var task2 = new Task(()=> job2());
    task2.ContinueWith(previousTask =>{
        //do task in UI thread...
    },TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()); 
    task2.Start();            
  }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
task.Start();
```

Comment: Look into `async` and `await`, though I personally always go for `BackgroundWorker` when I want to update the UI and perform the logic in the background - you just can't go wrong with it.

Comment: Don't nest, just add two more ContinueWith().

Comment: @Hans would you be more specific on using "two more ContinueWith()"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear to me what the `enterPop()` and `exitPopup()` methods are supposed to do, as the code example is missing that detail. Maybe they are displaying some kind of window in the GUI? It's also not clear what code exists in the "check result of job 1" part, "do task in UI thread", etc.

Without these details, it's impossible to know what your code is actually doing.

In any case, Hans's advice is correct. It's not really clear from the incomplete code example why you get the behavior you're seeing (for that matter, it's not really entirely clear to me *what* behavior you're seeing). But it's likely that if you'd written the code in the more usual `async`/`await` pattern, it would work fine:

```
enterPop(PopupTypes.popup1);
await Task.Run(() => job1()); //task runs in another thread
//**back in UI thread**
//check result of job 1, start another popup in UI
exitPopup();
enterPop(PopupTypes.popup2);
// starts another background thread for task 2
await Task.Run(()=> job2());
exitPopup();
//do task in UI thread...
```

For bonus points, have the `job1()` and `job2()` methods return the result that you check (per the commend in your code), and use something like `var result = await Task.Run(() => job1());` to retrieve the value (instead of whatever mechanism you're using now).

Comment: +1 for `Task.Run`. The op's problem of running on the UI thread is caused by `Task.Start`, which *defaults to `TaskScheduler.Current`, not `TaskScheduler.Default`*. I describe this [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/02/a-tour-of-task-part-8-starting.html), and also [have a post with more details on why this is confusing](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html). `Task.Run` does not have this odd default scheduler behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases TaskScheduler may decide to execute Task in the current thread, e.g. read the following example from Jeffrey Richter's book CLR via c#:

> When a thread calls the Wait method, the system checks if
>   the Task that the thread is waiting for has started executing. If it
>   has, then the thread calling Wait will block until the Task has
>   completed running. But if the Task has not started executing yet, then
>   the system may (depending on the TaskScheduler) execute the Task using
>   the thread that called Wait. If this happens, then the thread calling
>   Wait does not block; it executes the Task and returns immediately

I believe something similar happens in your logic. TaskScheduler just follows your task queue and decides to execute it syncronously. The easiest way out is to start task2 in default scheduler

```
task2.Start(TaskScheduler.Default);
```